# How to block users to close the window in Oracle APEX builder

Tags: javascript, apex

I have a APEX screen, where I have button to go back to the calling EBS home page. I do not want the users to directly close the window, as by doing that my EBS session will also get closed.

I tried creating a "**Page Unload**" dynamic action. And executing the below Javascript on its TRUE action :

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
}
```

But it is not working.

Can you please let us know, how can we do that ? How to hide or disable or block the Close  (X) icon on the top of the window ?

Comment: Appreciate if somebody could help me give a quick solution t this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is that `unload` event happens after the `onbeforeunload` event, so you're setting up the handler too late. If you execute the above JavaScript in the **Page Load** dynamic action, `confirmExit` will run when the user tries to close the window (or tab.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but wven after putting the code in page load dynamic action. It is not working :(

Comment: Thanks @Polly Shaw. I tried this again after several days and suddenly this worked. But now the new problem that is arising is that the prompt is coming even if I am clicking any button on the screen. I just want it when we click on close (X) window. Any idea how can we restrict this prompt on click of the buttons? Thanks in advance for your help.